# Local variable name 'choice' cannot be declared because it would give different meaning to 'choice'

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Sorry, I'm completely new to the programming world.  I'm creating a console application that basically takes your input on whether you want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit or vice-versa.

The problem I'm running into is:

> "Error   3 A local variable named 'choice' cannot be declared in this
>   scope because it would give a different meaning to 'choice', which is
>   already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

I tried looking at other examples, but they were far more complicated than my brain can understand for now.

```
namespace TemperatureApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int choice;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hi! This is a temperatue app");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for C to F or 2 for F to C");
                //take the user input
                int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Great, you chose C to F. Now enter the temp.");
                    int celcius = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    //next line use the formula and show answer
                }
                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Great, you chose F to C. Now enter the temp.");
                    int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    //next line use the formula and show answer
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not the right choice.");
                    //In this way, keep asking the person for either 1 or two

            }
            while (choice != 1 || choice != 2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it failing here:  `if (choice == 2)`?

Answer (score 7):

```
int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

should read

```
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

By putting the `int` in the second time, you are declaring another variable called "choice" inside the {}. That definition is conflicting with the one just outside.

Comment: Sure. Pick the answer here you like best, and click the checkmark. It tells other people this question has been answered.

Comment: True @user2054277, it's also nice if you up-vote any others you also found helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the error message, you have declared your *choice* variable twice within the same scope.

When you read the value from the console input you don't need to re-declare the variable you just need set it. To elaborate:

```
int choice; // declare variable

do
{
    int choice = ...; // re-declare variable
}
```

On the second line you want to *assign* the variable a value, not re-declare it, to do that you just need to replace this line:

```
int choice = ...
```

With

```
choice = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I'm running into is:
>
> "A local variable named 'choice' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'choice', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else".
>
> I tried looking at other examples

You shouldn't look at examples, but at the error and your code. The C# compiler is quite user-friendly with its messages, and this one is quite clear also. You just have to understand the language used.

> A local variable named 'choice' cannot be declared

You declare a variable like this: `variable-type variable-name`, which happens on the line of the error, within your `do`-loop:

```
int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Here with `int` you *declare* the variable, `int` being its type. Removing `int` will make that line an [*assignment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator), which is what you need. The result of `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` is assigned (=) to the `choice`-variable. You can only assign a variable after declaring it, but you have already done that earlier in the code. So the error says:

> because it would give a different meaning to 'choice', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

And if you look up in your code, you see that in a [parent scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) (in `static void Main()`) a variable with the same name is declared:

```
int choice;
```

Now you should know you only need to declare a variable once, and that this is usually, preferably done in a scope as small as possible. In your case, you can simply remove the `int` before `int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`, because you also need to access `choice` outside the `do`-loop.

Comment: I disagree.  It's used in the condition of his loop; a declaration made inside the loop body will not be visible there.

Comment: @BenVoigt oops, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the deep analysis. This definitely helps in learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the choice variable declaration out of your cycle scope. Like this:

```
   int choice;

   do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi! This is a temperatue app");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for C to F or 2 for F to C");
        //take the user input
        choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if (choice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great, you chose C to F. Now enter the temp.");
            int celcius = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //next line use the formula and show answer
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great, you chose F to C. Now enter the temp.");
            int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //next line use the formula and show answer
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("That is not the right choice.");
            //In this way, keep asking the person for either 1 or two

    }
    while (choice != 1 || choice != 2);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a local variable named the same name as another local variable.  You *can* have a local variable with the same name as a variable of a larger, non-local scope (class member for instance) but in that case the local variable hides the larger-scoped variable.

What you want to do is take the `int` off the second `choice`.  You don't need to re-declare it, you just want to assign it.

```
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```